# How to do shopping cart payment option in angular 8

Tags: angular6, angular7, angular8

I have created one shoppping cart application.I do not know how to redirect payment option after filled all details.If anyone know please help me to find the solution.

src/app/directives/billing.dir.ts:

```
send(){  
 if(this.billingForm.valid){

  this.storage.set({
  customerInfo:this.billingForm.value
  })
  this.router.navigate(['/checkout']);

 }
 }
```

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-selvam-ecommerce-task-cnstaj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdirectives%2Fbilling.dir.ts

Comment: which payment gateway you trying?  most of payment come with javascript or other supported language SDK files.

Comment: I do not have any idea about that..This is first time i am trying so please tell me which payment gateway best and secure to pay.I want to implement in my angular8 project.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using only angular for payment then you have to **implement any payment_gateway (paytm or paypal etc)** in angular then send that information to that gateway.

OR

If you are using backed like Node.js then you can send that data to the server and implement that gateway on server-side

Then after sending that data to the gateway, it will return you the **URL**. then you have to redirect on that URL and made your payment.

You can ask for any help If you need.

Comment: How to send that data to the server and How to implement that gateway on server-side?

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to choose payment which you want to start with it.
2. After they will provide you integration kit for supported language mostly all payment gateway support JavaScript SDK.
3. Then you have to convert or use as it library inside angular project like importing library.

Before start payment integration get clarity on below article :

https://www.quora.com/How-do-payment-gateways-work-technically

https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-process-of-transaction-in-payment-gateway

https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-procedure-to-get-a-payment-gateway

https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-procedure-to-get-a-payment-gateway-for-my-website-in-India

They will provide Kit like this :

https://razorpay.com/integrations/

Demo Paytm Account you can follow this :

https://developer.paytm.com/docs/v1/payment-gateway/  and for going live

sign up here : https://business.paytm.com/payment-gateway

Comment: See this video: Title "Demo for Paytm checkout" https://developer.paytm.com/docs/v1/payment-gateway/      I am extecting like that so how can i integrate it?  Can you implement that one in my stackblitz?   YOUR_KEY_HERE just put for dummy key.

Comment: You can try and if anywhere we stuck you can ask. Payment gateway integration is separate task where people get paid for it. I recommend you try once and ask question if you stuck.

Comment: I do not have any server so how can i implement gateway payment like this:https://developer.payumoney.com/redirect/     and my stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-selvam-ecommerce-task-kezefg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: You have any solution?

Comment: solution is there. it will required time to integrate. As i said earlier people are getting paid for this kind of task. Stackoverflow is to help if you stuck somewhere.

Comment: Can i use this :  npm i payumoney-node

Comment: yes you can use this try this and ask different question for help. if you stuck

Comment: payumoney-node is safe?

Comment: developer just created wrapper on API. it will be safe.

Comment: How to use this:https://medium.com/@swapnilnakhate/payumoney-payment-gateway-integration-with-nodejs-f715e5fc25a

Comment: I have Merchant, Salt key, Authorization header but i do not know how to use it? i have downloaded two folder,one for nodejs and another one for angular 6 from https://medium.com/@swapnilnakhate/payumoney-payment-gateway-integration-with-nodejs-f715e5fc25a

Comment: How to integrate with these?please give me idea

Comment: I am waiting for your reply..please help me

Comment: Ok.Np..I am waiting

Comment: Back End (NodeJS) : https://github.com/SwapnilNakhate/PayUMoney-NodeJS.git

Comment: Front End (Angular 6) : https://github.com/SwapnilNakhate/PayUMoney-Angular6.git

Comment: Hi..you findout solutions?

Comment: I am getting this error:  http://localhost:8080/api/payment/pay net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED